Emacs M-s-b is undefined
Until recently I was able to use the ◆ (super) key on my keyboard as an alt key inside emacs.
I used xmodmap with
remove Mod4 = Super_L
keysym Super_L = Alt_L
add Mod1 = Super_L

to turn that super key into an extra alt key.
But recently something changed (software upgrade?)
and now emacs gives me an error when I press super-b (or super-anything).
M-s-b is undefined
When I use xev to check what is going on, I can't see a difference between alt-b and super-b.
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x614, subw 0x0, time 1539835469, (16,85), root:(811,644),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x614, subw 0x0, time 1539835893, (16,85), root:(811,644),
    state 0x8, keycode 56 (keysym 0x62, b), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (62) "b"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (62) "b"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x614, subw 0x0, time 1539836021, (16,85), root:(811,644),
    state 0x8, keycode 56 (keysym 0x62, b), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (62) "b"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x614, subw 0x0, time 1539836061, (16,85), root:(811,644),
    state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x614, subw 0x0, time 1539836373, (16,85), root:(811,644),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x614, subw 0x0, time 1539836637, (16,85), root:(811,644),
    state 0x8, keycode 56 (keysym 0x62, b), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (62) "b"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (62) "b"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x614, subw 0x0, time 1539836717, (16,85), root:(811,644),
    state 0x8, keycode 56 (keysym 0x62, b), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (62) "b"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x614, subw 0x0, time 1539836821, (16,85), root:(811,644),
    state 0x8, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

xmodmap -pm reports
xmodmap:  up to 6 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Super_L (0x85),  Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd),  Super_L (0xce)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        ISO_Level5_Shift (0xcb)
mod4        Super_R (0x86),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c)

super-b acts as an alt-b inside xterm.  super-mouse1 accomplishes the same function as alt-mouse1 in my fvwm.
How do I adjust things to make emacs work like it used to?

It seems that emacs no longer uses the configuration of xmodmap.
In order to make my super key act like a meta key once again I had to add
(setq x-super-keysym 'meta)
to my ~/.emacs configuration file.
(My emacs version is 29.3)
